# how to use route using an imaginary directory in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

who to make this work in local host ?
I have two codeigniter3 systems. e.g MyApp is the main application, and Service is just api service.
in the Service application, I have the services in the modules.
the structure is like this

```
modules/
       services/
        controllers/
                   Myservice->getAllStuff()
        models/
        views/
```

in the $route of this "Service" application, I placed something like this

```
$route['admin/services/list'] = 'services/Myservice/getAllStuff';
```

now back to the MyApp application. Inside one of my controllers I defined a const like this

```
const URL_SERVICE = 'service/admin/services/list'
```

When I used curl and passed that constant url(plus the localhost:8888 base url), I'm seeing an error log in my apache_error.log saying something like this

```
[error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/service/admin
```

why ah?, I thought the route of CI will just mask an existing directory/controller/function url? . did i do anything wrong?

Comment: It seems like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  [Did you read the documentation and do the tutorial?](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html#routing)  `$route['admin/services/list']` is only the URL as entered into the browser, and `'services/Myservice/getAllStuff'` is the actual CodeIgniter path to your function, `[controller-class]/[controller-method]/[arguments]`.

Comment: I actually tried to remove the "admin" string from the $route ...so it became $route['admin/services/list'] still doesn't work am getting the error in apache_error.log

Comment: The sequence of routes also matters where the higher routes take precedence.  If you have not read the entire CodeIgniter manual and done the tutorial yet, it only takes a few hours and you'll thank me later.

Comment: that one i posted above is actually the first one on my routes ....actually, it's a module not the typical controller class...so it's inside the module directory ....hence, ....modules/service/controllers/MyService->getAllStuff

Comment: Maybe that's the problem.  Please read the docs:  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: `services` would be considered as your `application` folder.  So then did you define the proper path to it via the `$application_folder` setting in your `index.php` file?

Comment: there's  a lot of different modules inside the modules directory .....the /service   directory i mentioned is just one of the other directories inside the modules folder...this microservices architecture is crazy, i dunno how to make this work in my localhost , mamp apache is dodging it

Comment: Regardless, CodeIgniter will never be able to find the Controllers if you don't define these things within the `index.php` file.  You need to set the correct paths for System, Application, and Views.

Comment: index.php $application_folder is good for one only right?..... the modules/ folder has lots of other folders inside, and each of the services inside, has it's own controllers , models, views directory

Comment: Yes.  Now you really **need** to go read the CodeIgniter documentation once and for all... you cannot dismantle the CI Application directory and expect it to function.  With version 3, the only thing you are allowed to remove from Application and place anywhere is Views (as per the setting in your `index.php`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was solve by just adding "index.php" within the const URL value.
like this

```
const URL_SERVICE = 'service/index.php/admin/services/list'
```

darn.. took me hours to figure this out lol..but at least case solved.